# External Monitor not detected in ubuntu 18.04, no detect displays button seen. NVIDIA x server setting shows only prime profiles

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am running ubuntu 18.04, for some time now. Recently when I tried to plug in an external LCD ti my laptop a DELL G3, ubuntu was not able to detect it. There was no detect displays option in settings and the NVIDIA X server settings shows only prime profiles and no other settings.[prime profiles displayed only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T44FD.png)
I have tried updating the drivers and reinstalling ubuntu but it doesnt work. Please if you could provide a solution.

Comment: did you found a solution?